# How do I sum multiple fields in doctrine odm?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I want to use doctrine odm's aggregation builder to build this query:

```
db.TeamStandings.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
                "team.$id": ObjectId("5a1643fdf5d8741a883c2aeb")
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": { "team": "team.$id" },

                // This is the sum of multiple fields
                "games": { $sum: { $sum: ["$wins", "$losses", "$ties"] } }, 

                "wins": { $sum: "$wins" },
                "losses": { $sum: "$losses" },
                "ties": { $sum: "$ties" },
                "homeWins" : { $sum: "$homeRecord.wins" },
                "homeLosses" : { $sum: "$homeRecord.losses" },
                "homeTies" : { $sum: "$homeRecord.ties" },
                "roadWins" : { $sum: "$roadRecord.wins" },
                "roadLosses" : { $sum: "$roadRecord.losses" },
                "roadTies" : { $sum: "$roadRecord.ties" },
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

I executed this in Studio3T and got the following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "team" : "team.$id"
    }, 
    "games" : NumberInt(776), 
    "wins" : NumberInt(377), 
    "losses" : NumberInt(398), 
    "ties" : NumberInt(1), 
    "homeWins" : NumberInt(218), 
    "homeLosses" : NumberInt(170), 
    "homeTies" : NumberInt(1), 
    "roadWins" : NumberInt(159), 
    "roadLosses" : NumberInt(228), 
    "roadTies" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

How do I write this exact query using doctrine odm's aggregation builder?

Comment: There's quite extensive documentation on the aggregation builder: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/aggregation-builder.html

Comment: Believe it or not, I have been to that page many times. That's how I got started with using the aggregation builder. However, I did not see where it covered summing multiple fields together. 

The specific case that I'm looking for is how to write this in doctrine odm:
`"games": { $sum: { $sum: ["$wins", "$losses", "$ties"] } },`

Comment: After digging through the doctrine odm `sum()` code, the doc-block says:
`Calculates and returns the sum of all the numeric values that result from
  applying a specified expression to each document in a group of documents that share the same group by key. Ignores nun-numeric values.`

But it seems it _doesn't_; or more likely I don't understand the aggregation builder.

Comment: You may want to update the question to say where you have troubles with ODM - as of now it looked like "I haven't tried but please rewrite this query to PHP"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is tricky because the documentation is not quite clear.

In theory, you create a nested sub-expression and use the sum operator there:

```
$builder = $this->dm->createAggregationBuilder(\Documents\BlogPost::class);
$builder->group()
    ->field('id')
    ->expression(null)
    ->field('games')
    ->sum($builder->expr()->sum('$wins', '$losses', '$ties'))
;
```

However, due to the way the aggregation builder is built, it doesn't quite understand the sum `syntax` with multiple expressions outside a `$project` stage, resulting in the following (wrong) result:

```
[{
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "games": { "$sum": { "$sum": "$wins" } }
    }
}]
```

To work around this problem, use the `$add` operator instead of `$sum` in the nested expression:

```
$builder = $this->dm->createAggregationBuilder(\Documents\BlogPost::class);
$builder->group()
    ->field('id')
    ->expression(null)
    ->field('games')
    ->sum($builder->expr()->add('$wins', '$losses', '$ties'))
;
```

This creates the aggregation pipeline you want it to create.

The reason this is weird is because the documentation defines different behavior for `$sum` when used in `$group` and `$project` stages: in `$group`, it accepts a single argument, while in `$project` it accepts multiple arguments. However, it is not perfectly clear how it behaves in a nested expression within `$group`: the fact that the aggregation pipeline you posted works suggests that it doesn't see the sub-expression as being within a `$group` stage, thus allowing multiple arguments. When I built the operator, I assumed the opposite: only when in a `$project` stage should `$sum` accept multiple arguments and default to the one argument syntax otherwise.

I'll create a ticket for this in MongoDB ODM and I'll see if this can easily be fixed.

Comment: using `->add(...)` worked! Thank you. And thanks for creating a ticket. Could you post the link for the ticket you created so I can follow? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, there you go: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1678